# Creating contract within contract and accessing via Web3

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am creating a contract (Exchange) within the Factory contract and I want to access via Web3 the Factory contract.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Exchange.sol";

contract Factory {
    mapping(address => address) public tokenToExchange;

    function createExchange(address _tokenAddress) public returns (address) {
        require(_tokenAddress != address(0), "invalid token address");
        require(
            tokenToExchange[_tokenAddress] == address(0),
            "exchange already exists"
        );

        Exchange exchange = new Exchange(_tokenAddress);
        tokenToExchange[_tokenAddress] = address(exchange);

        return address(exchange);
    }

    function getExchange(address _tokenAddress) public view returns (address) {
        return tokenToExchange[_tokenAddress];
    }
}
```

For example, I want to addLiquidity and for that I need access to Exchange contract. But before I want to check via getExchange() function within Factory contract if the Exchange() contract is already created.

```
  addLiquidity = async (tokenAmount: string, ethAmount: string) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let exchangeAddress: string;
    try {
      const factory = this.state.factory;
      const tokenAddress = this.state.tokenAddress;
      // if Exchange not already created then we will get of address(0) 
      0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      exchangeAddress = await factory.methods.getExchange(tokenAddress).call();
      if (exchangeAddress.startWith('0x00') {
      //Exchange address
      exchangeAddress = await factory.methods
        .createExchange(this.state.tokenAddress)
        .call();
      console.log(`Èxchange created at: ${exchangeAddress}`);
       }
      console.log('address already created')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      return;
    }
```

If I run the function getExchange(tokenAddress) is alway return the address of address(0) 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

If the return value is 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 the token does not yet have an exchange.
I think that is expected.

https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V1/guides/connect-to-uniswap#get-exchange-address